# Is NHibernate 2.1.2 compatible with .NET 4?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, .net-4.0

I'm looking for the "path of least resistance" (making as few code changes as possible), updating a current .NET 3.5 system to .NET 4.  The system currently uses NHibernate 2.1.2.  Will that version work under .NET 4, or must I update to NHibernate 3 as part of the migration?

Apologies if this question has been answered elsewhere - for some reason (perhaps PEBKAC) I cannot find specific release notes and compatibility notes for versions of NHibernate.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the usual corporate bureaucracy snafu, I don't yet have access to .NET 4 on my machine.  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's always recommended to upgrade to the latest release in order to take advantage of new features/bug fixes, I've used NHibernate 2.1.2 in a .net 4.0 app with no problems. Here's a little info on the release of [NHibernate 3.0](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/12/05/nhibernate-3-0-released.aspx)

Comment: easy migration NH 2.1.0.1002 to NH 3 ??